# How can I download a publicly shared Sharepoint Excel file?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use python to download this Excel file from Sharepoint programmatically. However, I'm not part of that organization, so I don't have a file path within the Sharepoint site. It's publicly shared (you can view the data just by opening it in a browser), so I assume there should be a way that I can download the data programmatically. I have tried all the other solutions in similar questions in Stack Overflow and it didn't work. Any ideas?

`https://editproj.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/Ea32XJl_g9VBreFAia_zMmEBY6FW2ZWh8F4VeJ1Rt5Z4YA`

Comment: If the link you had were a sharing link from OneDrive / SharePoint Online you could use the [use sharing link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint. Trying that with your provided URI returns a 400 error for invalid URI. Looking into alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found any workarounds yet.  Still getting an invalid URI when attempting other approaches.